# Get context of Listview item when Entry of the item is focused in a group list view

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have Grouped list view.
Each list item has an Entry in it.

How to get the context of the grouped list view item when its entry is focused?

My grouped list:

```
private ObservableCollection<Grouping_Activities> _laborMiscTimeList;
    public ObservableCollection<Grouping_Activities> LaborMiscTimeList
    {
        get { return _laborMiscTimeList; }
        set { _laborMiscTimeList = value; OnPropertyChanged("LaborMiscTimeList"); }
    }
```

This is the code on list item entry focus:

```
private void DriverNotes_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox("Notes");
        textBox.InputTextEntered += TextBoxPopup_InputTextEntered;
        PopupNavigation.PushAsync(textBox, true);
    }
```

Where TextBox is the popup and it has text box and save button. On clicking on save button, I have an event register as below:

```
private void TextBoxPopup_InputTextEntered(object sender, string e)
    {
        if(e != null)
        {
            DALaborMiscTime dALaborMiscTime = new DALaborMiscTime();
            //here i need to get the context of list item and stote that string to one of the item field in DB

          //  ((LaborMiscTime)this.BindingContext).Comments = e;
           //dALaborMiscTime.SaveDriverComments(((LaborMiscTime)this.BindingContext).MobileID, e);
        }
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: just check the control's BindingContext

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: Do you want to get the binding data for the item or the item itself ?

Comment: I want binding data of the whole list item.

Comment: when clicking on the entry control, I'm opening a popup and after entering text in that popup and clicking ok, the note should save to the list item and it should display on the list item entry. @Jason

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: I just added some code. can you please check? @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you need to get the data for a particular item that is focused,you should only do :**

```
private void DriverNotes_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = sender as Entry;
    var data = entry.BindingContext;

}
```

**if you want to get the data of the whole list ,you could get by the two ways:**

1.Use the model directly (e.g `ColorsDataMpdel.All`)

```
class ColorsDataModel
  { 
    public ObservableCollection<ColorsDataModel> All{get;set;}
  }
```

2.Use the `ItemsSource` property of ListView (e.g `mylistview.ItemsSource`)

```
<ListView x:Name="mylistview">
    ......
</ListView>
```

Comment: I was looking for first solution. Thanks.